# Downvoting when you are addicted to reputation

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

**Downvoting** gives you `-1` reputation, which is good. Otherwise users would just downvote anything that they find even remotely inappropriate. You can observe it on **Meta**, where reputation really doesn't matter at all. People are more likely to downvote, because they don't lose their own reputation.

I must admit, that I am addicted to reputation myself. I would never open a bounty and I also don't downvote. Instead I use flags and comments. I also find this more constructive.

**Please explain**, what benefits and consequences losing own reputation upon downvoting has. I would like to know more about it.

Comment: It takes one upvote to negate 10 downvotes. The reputation greed will diminish once you get some more, but still.

Comment: **side note** many times I downvote an answer, it gets deleted and I get my precious interweb points back

Comment: @MikeBeeler Since the cost of -1 applies only to downvoting answers, I think this is not a duplicate.

Comment: If you downvote really bad answers, they will normally get deleted anyway, and you'll get your rep back.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, most of the time I will go ahead and vote to close the question.

Comment: Pain is inextricably linked to pleasure.  Here, let me demonstrate as I downvote your question... Ouch! Mmmmmm....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It tends to discourage people from using downvotes frivolously.

Sure, you *could* be downvoting answers left and right. But you know that each downvote means slightly less status for yourself.

Eventually, you will achieve enlightenment. You will realize that Fake Internet Points are a means to an end, but not an end unto themselves. And then you will downvote.

Comment: This has a Catch-22, downvoting two answers while having 125 reputation D:.

Comment: @Braiam I tought users kept an earned privilege even if they drop below the rep requirement for it later?

Comment: @ivarni , No. if your reputation goes below the required rep for the privilege, then you will lose that privilege.

Answer (score 6):

Voting plays an important role in letting others know of the quality of a post. A post with a lot of up votes means that it is of high quality. But, we also need a mechanism to show that some posts contain problems. For such problems, please do down vote.

If you find a post that has issues, then down vote it ( and if possible, leave a comment on how to fix it, or fix it yourself by editing ). If it is an answer, you lose 1 reputation for the down votes, but if you had left a comment, the OP would notify if he/she edited and you can remove your down vote ( and if it is now of good quality, you can up vote it as well ) , or if it was deleted, you will get back the reputation.

But down votes on questions are free, you don't lose any reputation for down voting a question but that doesn't mean you shouldn't leave comments. And, you can just do as I said above.

So most of the time, you will get back the reputation because if it was low quality answer ( flag it as well ) or had some other, it would most likely be deleted.

As you get used to down voting, you will understand that the good feeling you get once you helped improve the quality of posts is not something you can get easily.

In this way, you can help moderate the Stack Overflow community and make it a better place with good quality posts.